# 10 second delay between login and shell prompt.

Tags: linux, bash, authentication

I've got a strange problem. After I enter my password on a debian 6.0 system, I get the motd but then there is a 5-10 second pause until I get a shell prompt. If I press ctrl-c during that pause the prompt comes up instantly. What could be happening here? Am I killing the login process? Why might it be taking so long to invoke bash? I appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this question is more appropriate to the [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) website

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can debug bash shell scripts using `set -x` and `set +x`. The `set -x` command enables debug mode and the `set +x` command disables it.

Putting `set -x` at the top of your $HOME/.bash_profile should cause debug information to be printed for your personal shell initialisation files. If as you say you get a 10 second delay you should be able to track it down quite easily. If This doesn't shed any light then go for the system wide initialisation file `/etc/profile`.

[Bash Debugging](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html) and [shell initialisation files](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/files.html)

Comment: Thanks, that helped me track it down to bash-completion! Apparently it does a lot of initialisation.

Comment: Thanks from me too! I had a very similar problem to this on a virtual system deployed from an OVA file into VMWare ESXi. I found (using set -x) that the problem was caused by a VMWare Tools script called /etc/profile.d/zzzz-vamilocale.sh, which was attempting to read OVF Environment settings via /opt/vmware/bin/ovfenv, which was in turn trying to fetch settings from various locations, including the CDROM. If the CD device was empty or not connected, this would cause the delay. Removing the script (which just sets/updates the LANG env var) was one simple solution!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. On an NVIDIA Jetson Xavier board running Ubuntu 18.04 (and I disabled the desktop environment), I found the culprit of slow startup time when running `bash --login` is from these files: `/etc/profile.d/jetson_env.sh` and `/etc/profile.d/input-method-config.sh`, so I renamed them and added suffix `.bak` to disable them. The delay was more than 1 second, and it affected both the SSH login process and "new-session", "new-window" operations in `tmux`, which were all very annoying.

Comment: Good point! In my case it was `kubectl completion bash` command that caused this delay.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely there's something in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. Or maybe some other startup file (`/etc/profile` et al).

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed in my .bashrc; bash-completion was the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Same problem as John Rix for me. /opt/vmware/bin/ovfenv was the culprit.

I found this post after doing the following investigation: 
starting another bash would take up to 30 seconds on a CentOS6

```
strace bash
```

shows few lines before it hangs:

```
read(3, "LANG=`/opt/vmware/bin/ovfenv --q"..., 183) = 183
```

Removed the script from being executed with:

```
mv /etc/profile.d/zzzz-vamilocale.sh /etc/profile.d/zzzz-vamilocale.sh.ko
```